# Ruby Script that runs list of irb watir commands

Tags: ruby, testing, watir, watir-webdriver, irb

I regularly use the irb for testing out cucumber watir webdriver steps on a browser. This involves opening the irb and typing in a list of the same commands. The first few commands are always

1. require 'watir-webdriver'
2. browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)
3. b.goto 'www.foo.com'

the list of commands goes on like this. Every time I open the irb I have to go through all of these. Does anyone have any idea of a script which could be run to automate a list of commands such as the above? So that it would open the IRB and then go through the commands one by one saving me load of time.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A couple of notes: watir-webdriver is deprecated, so I'd advise looking at the watir gem. And you're mixing `browser` and `b`, which will yield a `undefined local variable` error.

Comment: Was any of this helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do is create a `script.rb` file in the root project directory (or wherever you're starting IRB), and write out the Ruby you normally run. Then when you start IRB, just `load 'script.rb'`

However this won't work if you need access to your `browser` variable after setup. In that case it would make more sense to create a class.

### in `./test_browser.rb`

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'irb'

class TestBrowser < Watir::Browser
  def self.build
    browser = new(:chrome)
    browser.goto 'www.foo.com'
    # other setup steps
    browser # return the browser at the end of the method
  end
end

IRB.start
```

Then from the shell: `$ ruby ./test_browser.rb`

This will start up IRB with your class loaded. Then all you need to do is call the `.build` method and store the browser in a variable

```
browser = TestBrowser.build
```

Comment: Many thanks. Worked a treat. Forgot to reply till now.

Answer (score 0):

You can always spin up `irb` with a particular file in mind:

```
irb -r./startup.rb
```

Where `./startup.rb` is the path to whatever file you want to run first before opening the REPL shell.

It's pretty easy to make a wrapper script for this if you do it frequently enough. You can also invoke IRB manually inside a custom script of your own construction, much as `rails console` does.